# MySQL Can I Select Data from One table OR another Table?

Tags: php, mysql, select, authentication

I'm working on a login script (In HTML, PHP and MYSQL) for a website that has two account types: Account "A" and Account "B". Right now I have a radio select that lets the user select which type of account they have. But I want to clear up the login screen a bit and also enable the login form to fit in the header by removing the radio buttons completely.

How do I get the script to check first one table for results (username and password) and if no results are found check the next table (username and password) and then once it finds a match sends it to an account specific page?

In a nutshell, I want to remove the need for the radio buttons.

Edit: I don't get any errors, but the problem is it only selects from the first table: Here's my code:

```php
$q = "SELECT varone, vartwo 
    FROM tablea 
    WHERE (user_email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p'))
    UNION
    SELECT varthree, vartwo 
    FROM tableb
    WHERE (contact_email='$e' AND pass=SHA1('$p'))
    ";      
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Comment: Just going to throw my two cents in here. Wouldn't it be much easier to just set a column called `account_type` in the database?

Comment: I tried doing an if else statement but It turned out to be more complicated and kept getting errors. The Union thin in MySQL seems to be on the track that I'm looking for.

Comment: @Phil - Try using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` since `UNION` will eliminate duplicates (which I'm guessing you have in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 'first' AS source, ...
FROM firstable
WHERE (username = $user) and (password = $password)

UNION

SELECT 'second' as source, ...
FROM secondtable
WHERE (....)
```

Then simply check where the results came from in your code.

```
if ($row['source'] == 'first') { ... came from first table ... }
```

Should work, assuming the exact same username/password pair wouldn't appear in both tables.

Comment: A variation of this worked! Thanks, saved me a lot of headache!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_A where id = 6 union select * from table_b where other_id = 6;
```